# Can you pause Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I can't find a pause button in Terraria, is there one? If I press the escape key, it just brings up my inventory - I tried pressing different keys, but none of them seem to do anything.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can Alt-Tab out of the window, or simply click out of it if playing in windowed mode, and it will pause gameplay. It's hackish, but it does pause (you can also do this during loading, and it will keep loading).

As James has pointed out, this is **single-player only.** There is currently (and I doubt there ever will be) no multiplayer pause.

Comment: Note: this solution is for Windows only. For Macs, Command-tab instead.

Answer (score 35):

Game pauses automatically if you ALT+TAB to another program.

**UPDATE**: In [Terraria 1.0.4](http://www.terrariaonline.com/threads/1-0-4-change-log.25667/) devs added the following option related to pausing:

> - Added an option that will pause the game while talking to an NPC or opening your inventory in single player. It defaults to off.

[image]

Comment: Be warned! This method will not work while on a multiplayer server!

Answer (score 1):

If you hit escape then click on settings underneath the inventory icon it pauses the game